# How to run Celtx without gksudo

Tags: permissions

I use the screenwriting software Celtx on Ubuntu 12.04. It runs fine, except that I have to use the software regularly, and it asks me to enter the password every time I want to use it. I changed the permissions on /usr/local/celtx so that I could use it without gksudo. After that, the software opened without me having to enter the password, but my work wouldn't get saved. It gives me the following error message when I try to save it:

```
 Celtx was unable to save your project: [Exception... "Component  
returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)  
[nsIZipWriter.open]"  nsresult: "0x80520015  
(NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)"  location: "JS frame ::  
chrome://celtx/content/save.js :: archiveCeltxProject :: line 1568"   
data: no]
```

Any idea about how to fix this?

Lol yeah I changed that to my actual user name. This is what the file looks like -

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6            File: /etc/sudoers.tmp                              

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

#bhaskar ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/celtx/celtx
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have changed the permissions of `/usr/local/celtx` which is a very bad idea but have not also changed the permissions of wherever it is supposed to save your work.

Anyway, please don't do it this way. Changing the permissions of system folders is never a good idea. Instead, set up `sudo` to let you use this command with no password. Run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

```
youruser ALL=NOPASSWD:/path/to/celtx
```

So, assuming your username is `bob` and the celtx executable is in `/usr/local/bin`, you would add this line:

```
bob ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/celtx
```

Now you will be able to run `sudo celtx` without being prompted for a password, If even writing the `sudo` is too much, just add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias celtx='sudo celtx'
```

You can now simply run `celtx` and you will actually run `sudo celtx` without entering a password. I also suggest you put the permissions back to the way you found them.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this did not work. I ran sudo visudo, and the the sudoers file opened up in the terminal. I added the line at the bottom and saved it, but I still need to enter a password to open Celtx. I should make it clear that clicking the Celtx shortcut in Applications runs the command gksudo /path to celtx (if that makes a difference)

Comment: @user178834 sounds like a syntax error. Please [edit] your question, and show the current contents of your `/etc/sudoers` file. You _did_ change `bob` to your actual user name right?

Comment: Turns out it was a syntax error. My bad. Problem solved. Thanks a lot for the help!